# How to get checkbox which starts with specific id

Tags: jquery

I have multiple checkboxes but I want to get all the checkboxs that start with id `'isActive_'` .

Comment: `$(':checkbox[id^="isActive_"]')`

Answer (score 2):

Below selector will return all checkboxes with id start with `isActive`

```
$("[id^=isActive][type=checkbox]")
```

[jsfiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/m3gHG/)

Comment: will this code only pick checkboxes if USER have some textboxes also there who have share same ID start with isActive_

Comment: can i get multiple checkbox from this?

Comment: @user1280492 you will get multiple checkboxes, as you will see in the jsfiddler link.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
var value = 'isActive_';
$(":checkbox[id^=" + value + "]")
```

Comment: will this code only pick checkboxes if USER have some textboxes also there who have share same ID start with isActive_

Answer (score 0):

Multiple Same ID is not a good approach.. you can use class instead of ID

```
$('.isActive').attr('checked',true)
```

So if you have unique ID with isActive_SOMETHING then you can use this

```
$("[id^=isActive]").attr('checked',true);
```

Comment: This is not answer you should post this as comment

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("input:checkbox[id^=isActive_]")
```